# My application is closing,when i click the button

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.amarjeet.goal";
    TextView t1,t2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
    public void goal1(View view){
        t1=findViewById(R.id.t1);
      t1.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString())+1));
    }
    public  void goal2(View view){
        t2=findViewById(R.id.t2);
        t2.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString())+1));
    }
    public void winner(View view){
        Intent intent =new Intent(this,Winner.class);
        String msg;
        if(Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString()) > Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString())){
                            msg="Winner is Team B";}
        else if(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()) > Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString())) {
            msg = "Winner is Team A";
        }
        else
            {
            msg="Match is Draw";}
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, msg);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

> The Error showing is :::::: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                         Process: com.example.amarjeet.goal, PID: 24396
>                         java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6267)
>                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24763)
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                          Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6267) 
>                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24763) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
>                          Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence
>       android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
>                             at com.example.amarjeet.goal.MainActivity.winner(MainActivity.java:31)
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                             at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                             at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6267) 
>                             at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24763) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
>                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
>                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548) 
>                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                             at ``com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)   The
>       message show error in if statement i click my button it closes

Comment: post related code from xml file.

Comment: do chanes in your code like this `t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);`

Comment: @VishalYadav Assuming he's targeting Oreo, casting is no longer required for `findViewById()`

Comment: @MichaelDodd it is might be reason for `crash`

Comment: @VishalYadav Crash is happening on line 31, within the `winner()` method. If it was lack of casting then the crash would happen within the `goal1()` or `goal2()` methods.

Comment: @Amarjeet Did any of the answers below help you with this issue? If so, then please upvote and accept to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

One of your calls to `t1.getText()` or `t2.getText()` are performed when the textview is null. Check that they are referencing the right resource and that they are actually created at the time you are trying to call `getText()`.

Answer (score 0):

As Androidas points out, either `t1` or `t2` is `null` when `winner()` is called. However, this can be fixed by keeping a reference to your `TextView`s in your `onCreate()` method like so:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    t1 = findViewById(R.id.t1);
    t2 = findViewById(R.id.t2);
}
```

This ensures you'll always have a reference to `t1` and `t2` throughout the lifetime of your activity, assuming those IDs are valid of course. Also make sure you remove those assignments from your `goal1()` and `goal2()` methods i.e.

```
public void goal1(View view) {
  t1.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString())+1));
}

public void goal2(View view){
    t2.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString())+1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your views before you use it's variables or objects. You are binding `t1` and `t2` in separate methods and if you click on winner button before binding `t1` and `t2` its crashing. so below code may be help you.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.amarjeet.goal";
    TextView t1,t2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        t1=findViewById(R.id.t1);
        t2=findViewById(R.id.t2);
    }
    public void goal1(View view){

      t1.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString())+1));
    }
    public  void goal2(View view){

        t2.setText(""+(Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString())+1));
    }
    public void winner(View view){
        Intent intent =new Intent(this,Winner.class);
        String msg;
        if(Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString()) > Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString())){
                            msg="Winner is Team B";}
        else if(Integer.parseInt(t1.getText().toString()) > Integer.parseInt(t2.getText().toString())) {
            msg = "Winner is Team A";
        }
        else
            {
            msg="Match is Draw";}
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, msg);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```